# Nesting XML from a SQL Query - Problems

Tags: sql, xml

So here is the finished product I am looking for:

```
<GPAutoActions>
 <createDispute>
  <transaction>
    <defaultKey>
      <custNo>10000000-AD</custNo>
      <invNo>28893848</invNo>
    </defaultKey>
  </transaction>
  <reason>405</reason>
  <amount>185.17</amount>  
  <pnote>Notes</pnote>
  <owner>LARRYGIST</owner>
 </createDispute>
</GPAutoActions>
```

Here is the table Structure

```
custno          invno    reason amount  pnote   owner
117455521-AD    28894882    405 972.04  Note    LARRYGIST
128623268-AD    28887277    405 182.99  Note    LARRYGIST
131537715-AD    28893848    405 185.17  Note    LARRYGIST
189063783-AD    28927273    405 777.49  Note    LARRYGIST
```

Here is the SQL I am using:

```
Select 1 as TAG
, null as parent
, null as 'createDispute!1!'
, null as 'transaction!2!Element'
, null as 'defaultKey!3!'
, null as 'defaultKey!3!custno!Element'
, null as 'defaultKey!3!InvNo!Element'
, null as 'reason!4!'
UNION ALL
Select 2 as Tag
, 1 as Parent
, Null
, NULL
, null
, null
, null
, null
Union ALL
Select 3 as Tag
, 2 as Parent
, Null
, NULL
, null
, custno
, InvNo
, null
FROM [GetPaid_Sandbox].[dbo].[DisputeData]
Union ALL
Select 4 as Tag
, 2 as Parent
, Null
, NULL
, null
, null
, null
, reason
FROM [GetPaid_Sandbox].[dbo].[DisputeData]
for XML EXPLICIT
```

Here is what is being returned:

```
<createDispute>
  <transaction>
    <defaultKey>
      <custno>117455521-AD</custno>
      <InvNo>28894882</InvNo>
    </defaultKey>
    <defaultKey>
      <custno>128623268-AD</custno>
      <InvNo>28887277</InvNo>
    </defaultKey>
    <defaultKey>
      <custno>131537715-AD</custno>
      <InvNo>28893848</InvNo>
    </defaultKey>
    <defaultKey>
      <custno>189063783-AD</custno>
      <InvNo>28927273</InvNo>
    </defaultKey>
    <reason>405</reason>
    <reason>405</reason>
    <reason>405</reason>
    <reason>405</reason>
  </transaction>
</createDispute>
```

What I do not understand is why the `<transaction>` tag is not closing after each `<defaultKey>` tag? I also will need to add the remainder of the tags after reason code, but I am stuck right here. Should I be using Explicit or will PATH work better in this situation? I hate having to do this from SQL but I am not sure how else to get it done easily.

Comment: The first image is the structure I am looking for similar to this:

Comment: See the filled in data above.

Comment: Where is *10000000-AD* CustNo from sample data? And why only third row values? What about the other rows? Explain why only one set of values are retained.

Comment: I was just typing an example number. I want each row of data in the DB to return a result set, but I just can't figure out why the transaction tag is not closing after the defaultKey tag/

Answer (score 1):

From your code I assume this is SQL Server. But this is not entirely sure... Hope, that my magic crystal ball is working well. Next time please sepcify the actual RDBMS (vendor and version).

Using `FOR XML EXPLICIT` is a pain in the neck... This was a good approach centuries ago, today one should prefer `FOR XML PATH`.

Your goal is easily achieved with this:

```sql
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(custno VARCHAR(100),invno INT,reason INT,amount DECIMAL(10,4),pnote VARCHAR(100),[owner] VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES
 ('117455521-AD',28894882,405,972.04,'Note','LARRYGIST')
,('128623268-AD',28887277,405,182.99,'Note','LARRYGIST')
,('131537715-AD',28893848,405,185.17,'Note','LARRYGIST')
,('189063783-AD',28927273,405,777.49,'Note','LARRYGIST');
```

--The query will create the XML as shown in your *finished product*

```
SELECT custno AS [transaction/defaultKey/custNo]
      ,invno AS  [transaction/defaultKey/invNo]
      ,reason
      ,amount
      ,pnote
      ,[owner]
FROM @mockup 
WHERE invno=28893848
FOR XML PATH('createDispute'),ROOT('GPAutoActions');
```

The result

```
<GPAutoActions>
  <createDispute>
    <transaction>
      <defaultKey>
        <custNo>131537715-AD</custNo>
        <invNo>28893848</invNo>
      </defaultKey>
    </transaction>
    <reason>405</reason>
    <amount>185.1700</amount>
    <pnote>Note</pnote>
    <owner>LARRYGIST</owner>
  </createDispute>
</GPAutoActions>
```

Hint: `FOR XML EXPLICIT` is still the right choice if one needs `CDATA` sections or very fance tricks with namespaces.

But I do not understand your comment: *I want each row of data in the DB to return a result set*.

Might be you are looking for this:

```
SELECT outerTable.invno
,(
    SELECT innerTable.custno AS [transaction/defaultKey/custNo]
          ,innerTable.invno AS  [transaction/defaultKey/invNo]
          ,innerTable.reason
          ,innerTable.amount
          ,innerTable.pnote
          ,innerTable.[owner]
    FROM @mockup AS innerTable
    WHERE innerTable.invno=outerTable.invno
    FOR XML PATH('createDispute'),ROOT('GPAutoActions'),TYPE
 )
 FROM @mockup AS outerTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

First: It looks like you have messed up in setting the parent for the reason element. Your spec indicates that you would like `reason` to be a child element of the `createDispute` element. However; your query has it set as a child element of the `transaction` instead.

To correct that, change the `parent` value for the query that returns `reason` from `2` to `1`. You can then return `amount`, `pnote`, and `order` from that same query.

Next: You don't need the 5th column (`defaultKey!3!`) - delete it in all queries.

Then: Change `null as 'createDispute!1!'` to `custno + '_' + cast(invno as varchar(50)) as 'createDispute!1!'`. Also code the 3rd returned value for each additional query as `custno + '_' + cast(invno as varchar(50))` instead of returning null.

Finally: `ORDER BY custno + '_' + cast(invno as varchar(50))`. This is the "special sauce" that ties everything together.

That should do it. Happy coding!

TL:DR (refactored):

```
Select 1 as TAG
, null as parent
, custno + '_' + cast(invno as varchar(50)) as 'createDispute!1!'
, null as 'transaction!2!reason!Element'
, null as 'transaction!2!amount!Element'
, null as 'transaction!2!pnote!Element'
, null as 'transaction!2!owner!Element'
, null as 'defaultKey!3!custno!Element'
, null as 'defaultKey!3!InvNo!Element'
FROM [GetPaid_Sandbox].[dbo].[DisputeData]
UNION ALL
Select 2 as Tag
, 1 as Parent
, custno + '_' + cast(invno as varchar(50))
, reason
, amount
, pnote
, [owner]
, null
, null
FROM [GetPaid_Sandbox].[dbo].[DisputeData]
Union ALL
Select 3 as Tag
, 2 as Parent
, custno + '_' + cast(invno as varchar(50))
, NULL
, NULL
, NULL
, NULL
, custno
, InvNo
FROM [GetPaid_Sandbox].[dbo].[DisputeData]
Union ALL
ORDER BY custno + '_' + cast(invno as varchar(50))
for XML EXPLICIT
```

Comment: If you are not tied to SQL-Server 2000 you should prefer `FOR XML PATH`

Comment: That is an entirely dogmatic point of view. In simple cases, it is little more than a style preference between how you want to structure the shape of your generated XML payload. In more complex cases, `FOR XML PATH` has been known to perform slower than `EXPLICIT` mode. If the question were truly about what "should" be done, then the answer would be that it should not be done in SQL at all. It should be offloaded to app code if at all possible. The OP was asking how to accomplish the task with `EXPLICIT` mode - not how best to accomplish the task.

Comment: Well, this is your opinion... Why should this be moved to app code, especially with more complex XMLs? Set-based operations should take place within the RDBMS. `FOR XML EXPLICIT` was good about 15 years ago. `FOR XML PATH` and the whole native XML type has evolved quite a bit since then...

Comment: I don't understand how you are qualifying this as a set-based operation. Set-based operations deal with data retrieval and aggregation rather than transformation. Pushing this logic into the database would be inappropriate in the vast majority of cases as translation should occur outside of the context of the persistence layer.

Comment: You were speaking about *more complex cases*. This let me think about hierarchically nested XMLs with a more complex, *multi-table* data source...

Comment: You could still use multiple set-based operations to pull all of the data required from the persistence layer and perform the final translation within app code. In the end it would perform better while not asking a centralized resource to do any more work than it absolutely needs to. Database servers are expensive and are almost always shared by multiple systems, while most systems are installed on their own cheap hardware that is easily scaled.

Comment: Okay, this last point is yours... It can be very important to keep the workload off the database server... As always: It depends... Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

Consider a nested query:

```sql
SELECT 1 as TAG
, null as parent
, (SELECT 1 AS [Tag], NULL AS [Parent], sub.custno AS 'defaultKey!1!custno!Element', sub.invno AS 'defaultKey!1!invno!Element'
   FROM DisputeData sub
   WHERE d.custno = sub.custno
   FOR XML EXPLICIT, TYPE)  AS 'createDispute!1!transaction!Element'

, d.reason as 'createDispute!1!reason!Element'
, d.amount as 'createDispute!1!amount!Element'
, d.pnote as 'createDispute!1!pnote!Element'
, d.owner as 'createDispute!1!owner!Element'
FROM DisputeData As d
FOR XML EXPLICIT, ROOT('GPAutoActions');
```

[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/WAIMII87571)

Unfortunately, result here returns the well-known issue of [repeated namespaces](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+server+repeat+namespaces+site:stackoverflow.com&client=firefox-b-1-ab&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjglrKv9orbAhUGiIMKHTN2CjMQrQIINSgEMAA&biw=1680&bih=881) in the nested element *defaultKey*, here being an empty one: `xmlns=""`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<GPAutoActions>
  <createDispute>
    <transaction>
      <defaultKey xmlns="">
        <custno>117455521-AD</custno>
        <invno>28894882</invno>
      </defaultKey>
    </transaction>
    <reason>405</reason>
    <amount>972.04</amount>
    <pnote>Dispute Reason: Inbound email from John requesting that account be cancelled, providing letter of cancellation. Attachments: Yes</pnote>
    <owner>LARRYGIST</owner>
  </createDispute>
  <createDispute>
    <transaction>
      <defaultKey xmlns="">
        <custno>128623268-AD</custno>
        <invno>28887277</invno>
      </defaultKey>
    </transaction>
    <reason>405</reason>
    <amount>182.99</amount>
    <pnote>Dispute Reason: Inbound email from Catherine requesting cancelation of services. Attachments: Yes</pnote>
    <owner>LARRYGIST</owner>
  </createDispute>
  <createDispute>
    <transaction>
      <defaultKey xmlns="">
        <custno>131537715-AD</custno>
        <invno>28893848</invno>
      </defaultKey>
    </transaction>
    <reason>405</reason>
    <amount>185.17</amount>
    <pnote>Dispute Reason: Syed stated that he canceled his Tyco contract a long time ago. Syad stated that he doesn't have an email address and didn't want to send CR a cancellation notice.  Attachments: No</pnote>
    <owner>LARRYGIST</owner>
  </createDispute>
  <createDispute>
    <transaction>
      <defaultKey xmlns="">
        <custno>189063783-AD</custno>
        <invno>28927273</invno>
      </defaultKey>
    </transaction>
    <reason>405</reason>
    <amount>777.49</amount>
    <pnote>Dispute Reason: Spoke to Grant stated moved out of building on 12 01 2017. Stated company that bought building decided not to go with Tyco and Tyco came and picked up the equipment. Attachments: No</pnote>
    <owner>LARRYGIST</owner>
  </createDispute>
</GPAutoActions>
```